# Read-only access for Gmail IMAP to connect

Tags: php, zoho

I like to get connected for read-only access only in this github repo- [AroundZOHO](https://github.com/observo/AroundZOHO) . How can I achieve it?

```
$inbox = imap_open(EMAIL_HOSTNAME,EMAIL_USERNAME,EMAIL_PASSWORD) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error()); 
$date = date("d M Y", strToTime ( "-1 days" )); 
$emails = imap_search($inbox, "SINCE \"$date\"", SE_UID);
```